# devise user_signed_in? How does it work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, security, devise

In the devise source code listed here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb

What exactly does line 56 do? In other words, I am not sure how devise determines whether a user is signed in.

It looks like it calls warden.authenticate with the scope of user(provided that user is what the model is)

Would I have to dive into the Warden codebase as well?

Answer (score 3):

Devise delegates the work to warden. Warden checks if the username and password are valid.

```
Warden::Strategies.add(:my_strategy) do

  def valid?
    params[:username] && params[:password]
  end

  def authenticate!
    u = User.find_by_username_and_password(
      params[:username],
      params[:password] # you should encrypt this. ;)
    )

    u.nil? ? fail!("Couldn't log in") : success!(u)
  end
end
```

Comment: Not sure if relevant. But I am mainly asking because I use Devise as part of an API authentication system and I rely on user_signed_in to determine whether a user should be able to consume the API(in addition to the presence of params[:auth_token]. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer.